# How to make an arrow of the desired shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, matrices, draw, tikz-matrix

I'm doing a presentation on derivatives and I thought about using a matrix to explain the derivative of a function.

It is the first time that I am doing something like this and I am having a little difficulty and I am not finding materials to help me, some commands that I found are giving many errors.

The image below is how it is at the moment:

[image]

The commands used in this image are:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 & f(x) & = & \sqrt{x^2 + 500^2} \cdot 640,00 & + &  (2000 - x) \cdot 312,00\\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  \\
   &  &  & {\color{red}\downarrow} &  & {\color{red}\downarrow} \\
 &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
\Rightarrow & f'(x) & = & 640,00\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2 + 500^2}}2x & + & 312,00(-1) 
\end{array} 
\]

\end{frame}
```

In place of the arrows I would like to put an arrow like the figure below:

[image]

One last question, I want to initially present the derivative of the first installment and use the \ pause command. Is there a possibility that only the first arrow and the first portion of the derivative will appear on the slide and then the rest on the next? The bottom line appears before the second arrow.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please show us what you try so far.. The complete small document, which produce showed image, will be very fine.

Comment: Added commands in text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\newcommand\myarrow{%
  \tikz\draw[red,dashed,thick,-Triangle] (0,0) -- ++(0,-1.1);%
}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\newcommand\myarrow{%
  \tikz\draw[red,dashed,thick,-Triangle] (0,0) -- ++(0,-1.1);
}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{cccccc}
 & f(x) & = & \sqrt{x^2 + 500^2} \cdot 640,00 & + &  (2000 - x) \cdot 312,00\\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  \\
   &  &  & \myarrow &  & \myarrow \\
 &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
\Rightarrow & f'(x) & = & 640,00\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2 + 500^2}}2x & + & 312,00(-1) 
\end{array} $

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was very good. To make the presentation, I'm trying to use the \pause command, but I would like the first part of the second line to appear only, is it possible to do this?

Comment: I don't know if I can only do it with the \pause command or if there is some other way.

Comment: I'm going to write another question about this, because I think it's a little confusing all the same. Thanks for your reply and help.